# DOM Scripting Javascript, set element value

Tags: javascript, dom

I am aiming to add a button to the screen through the click of another button.
I can successfully add them but they are blank (i.e, No text).

I tried setting the value with this technique:

```
addButton.setAttribute("value", "Click Me");
```

This failed, the strange thing is I was able to successfully set the 
elements ID with the setAttribute function.

I then tried the following:

```
var x = document.getElementById("buttonId");
x.value="Click Me";
```

The above caused the button not to add at all.

Maybe I'm missing something but I can't think why the first method
wouldn't work.

Note: These buttons are all created on the fly so the standard:

```
<input type="button" value="click me"/>
```

won't suffice.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What kind of DOM element is your button? div, button, input?

Comment: use just .value = or .text =

Comment: Where is your code for appending the button?

Comment: working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2fXK/) that does what you said doesn't work

Comment: Your fiddle works fine with me. Adds a button with text "hello". Which browser are you using?

Comment: @levi, it's a button element

Comment: @thsorens, I am using chrome.

Comment: code for appending: inputContainer.appendChild(button);

Comment: does your fiddle not work for you? Like i said, it added a button with text "hello" when i ran it, so it seems to be working. Could it be caching issues? Or just browser incompatibility? I tried it with firefox.

Comment: No1_Melman, I used createElement("button") as opposed to createElement("input")

Comment: Changing the the latter and then setting the type after has actually solved the problem.

Comment: I also have another similar DOM related question. Is it best to edit this Q or post a new one?

Comment: here is for a button [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2fXK/1/)

Comment: yes it is better to post separate question

Comment: No1_Melman, that's interesting, what's the reason behind needing to user innerHTML for the button ? It tripped me up because in regular HTML you can use the value property.

Comment: @AnonOmus No, [using a value attribute on a button element does nothing](http://jsfiddle.net/csVts/2/). A button element's value is specified between its tags. That's why modifying its `innerHTML` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addButton(elementId, value, name, type) {
    //Create an input type dynamically.   
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element. 
    element.type = type;
    element.value = value; // Really? You want the default value to be the type string?
    element.name = name;  // And the name too?

    var foo = document.getElementById(elementId);
    //Append the element in page (in span).  
    foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

Try this.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kailashyadav/4Q8Fd/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a button, associated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2fXK/1/):

```
$('#createButton').on('click', function () {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = 'hello';
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    $('#placeForButton').html(button);
});
```

Note I set the innerHTML, because an `input` relies on a `value` attribute, a `button` relies on an open and closing HTML attribute. Therefore, the value in between the tags is what sets the `button` text. This translates into `innerHTML`.

I only used JQuery to bind an event to the button click.